# What are the necessary permission to send an email on behalf of a user with Microsoft Graph?

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

For a few days now I'm struggling to implement a feature where the user can authenticate using their outlook email and schedule an email to be send. Therefore, the API should be able to send an email on behalf of the authenticated user.

The authentication flow works correctly and I'm able to save the access token. Also the Graph me call works as expected. I get the expected response back with the users data.

The problem is when I'm trying to send the email. I get the following error:

```
{"statusCode":401,"code":null,"requestId":null,"date":"2023-04-21T14:18:46.748Z","body":{"_writeState":{"0":0,"1":0},"_readableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":16384,"buffer":{"head":null,"tail":null,"length":0},"length":0,"pipes":null,"pipesCount":0,"flowing":null,"ended":false,"endEmitted":false,"reading":false,"sync":false,"needReadable":false,"emittedReadable":false,"readableListening":false,"resumeScheduled":false,"emitClose":true,"autoDestroy":false,"destroyed":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","awaitDrainWriters":null,"multiAwaitDrain":false,"readingMore":false,"decoder":null,"encoding":null},"readable":true,"_events":{"error":[null,null]},"_eventsCount":6,"_writableState":{"objectMode":false,"highWaterMark":16384,"finalCalled":false,"needDrain":false,"ending":false,"ended":false,"finished":false,"destroyed":false,"decodeStrings":true,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","length":10,"writing":true,"corked":0,"sync":false,"bufferProcessing":false,"writelen":10,"afterWriteTickInfo":null,"bufferedRequest":null,"lastBufferedRequest":null,"pendingcb":1,"prefinished":false,"errorEmitted":false,"emitClose":true,"autoDestroy":false,"bufferedRequestCount":0,"corkedRequestsFree":{"next":null,"entry":null}},"writable":true,"allowHalfOpen":true,"_transformState":{"needTransform":false,"transforming":true,"writechunk":{"type":"Buffer","data":[31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,10]},"writeencoding":"buffer"},"_hadError":false,"bytesWritten":0,"_handle":{"buffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,10]},"availOutBefore":16384,"availInBefore":10,"inOff":0,"flushFlag":2},"_outBuffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[85,85,85,85,85,85,80,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},"_outOffset":0,"_chunkSize":16384,"_defaultFlushFlag":2,"_finishFlushFlag":2,"_defaultFullFlushFlag":3,"_maxOutputLength":2147483647,"_level":-1,"_strategy":0}}
```

I think I'm not using the correct permission, but I've tried many (All the commented out permission as well) of them and still getting the same error message. I'm running out of options.

Do you guys know what might go wrong here?

Thanks in advance

I've used the following code to authenticate the user and send an email:

```
import * as msal from "@azure/msal-node";
import { Client } from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client";

export const msalConfig: msal.Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: “CLIENT_ID”,
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENENT_ID”,
    clientSecret: “CLIENT_SECRET”,
  },
};

export const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

export const getGraphClient = (accessToken: string | null) => {
  const graphClient = Client.init({
    authProvider: (done) => {
      done(null, accessToken);
    },
  });
  return graphClient;
};

export const protectedResources = {
  graphMe: {
    meEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
    usersEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/",
    scopes: [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "user.read",
      "mail.send",
      "offline_access",
      //  "Mail.Send",
      //  "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
      //  "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send.Shared",
      //  "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read",
      //  "https://graph.microsoft.com/profile",
      //  "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
      //  "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All",
    ],
  },
};
```

```
// Code to start the authentication flow
const state = request.query.state as string;

try {
    // Get the authorization URL
    const authCodeUrlParameters: msal.AuthorizationUrlRequest = {
        scopes: protectedResources.graphMe.scopes,
        redirectUri: "https://example.com/outlookOauth2Callback",
        codeChallengeMethod: "S256",
        state: state,
    };
    const authorizeUrl = await cca.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters);
    response.redirect(authorizeUrl);
    return;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    response.status(500).send(error);
    return;
}
```

```
// Code to get the access Token
const code = request.query.code as string;
const state = request.query.state as string; 
try {
    const tokenRequest: msal.AuthorizationCodeRequest = {
        code: code,
        scopes: protectedResources.graphMe.scopes,
        redirectUri:
        "https://example.com/outlookOauth2Callback",
        codeVerifier: request.query.code_verifier as string,
    };

    const accessToken = await cca.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest);
    await saveUserToken(code, accessToken);
    console.log("Successfully authorized");
    response.redirect("https://example.com/callback.html?code=" + code + "&state=" + state);
     return;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    response.status(500).send(error);
    return;
}
```

```
// Code to send the email
const graphUser = await getGraphClient(token.accessToken)
      .api(protectedResources.graphMe.meEndpoint)
      .get();

functions.logger.log("Graph User: " + JSON.stringify(graphUser));

const message = {
      subject: subject,
      body: {
        contentType: "HTML",
        content: body,
      },
      toRecipients: [
        {
          emailAddress: {
            toName: toName,
            address: toEmail,
          },
        },
      ],
      from: { emailAddress: { fromName: fromName, address: graphUser.email } },
};

const response = await getGraphClient(token[1].accessToken)
   .api(protectedResources.graphMe.usersEndpoint + `${graphUser.id}/sendMail`)
   .post({ message });

functions.logger.log("Response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
```

Answer (score 0):

To send an email on behalf of a user with Microsoft Graph, the application needs to be authorized with the necessary delegated permissions. These permissions include:

1. Mail.Send - allows the app to send mail as the signed-in user
2. Mail.ReadWrite - allows the app to read, create and modify email messages in the signed-in user's mailbox
3. User.Read - allows the app to read the basic profile of signed-in user, including their email address

To add these permissions, you need to go to the Azure Portal -> App Registration -> Your Application -> API Permissions and add these permissions. Additionally, you need to acquire an access token with the appropriate scopes to make API calls.

Comment: Hi ABward, 

Thank you for your fast answer.
I've made sure that I have these 3 delegate permission under the App Registration on Azure Portal and in code as well when authenticating and I'm still getting the same error. 

Are you here "Additionally, you need to acquire an access token with the appropriate scopes to make API calls" referring to other permission then the once you've mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

For sending the Mial "Mial.send" permission is enough, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#permissions).

For sending the mail:

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const sendMail = {
  message: {
    subject: 'Meet for lunch?',
    body: {
      contentType: 'Text',
      content: 'The new cafeteria is open.'
    },
    toRecipients: [
      {
        emailAddress: {
          address: 'frannis@contoso.onmicrosoft.com'
        }
      }
    ],
    ccRecipients: [
      {
        emailAddress: {
          address: 'danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  saveToSentItems: 'false'
};

await client.api('/me/sendMail')
    .post(sendMail);
```

Check your access token [here](https://jwt.io/) and see if the necessary permissions are present.

For more information refer this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#example-1-send-a-new-email-using-json-format

Comment: Hi Mehtab,

That's exactly why I've asked the question, because according with the documentation Mail.Send should be enough, but I'm still getting the same error. And I have no idea what the issue could be. 

Here are the scopes under the access token: 
"scp": "Mail.Read Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send openid profile User.Read email",